# How to resolve JasperReports Server (JRS) select boxes auto-close bug (with Firefox and other browsers)?

Tags: jasperserver

There's a [known bug](https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/12986) where JasperReports server (e.g. version *7.2*, but not *6.3.1*) report filter select boxes auto-close immediately after clicking them (e.g. with *Firefox 79* till *83* or *Waterfox G4.1.2*).

All the **server-side workarounds documented there, mainly CSS fixes, did not help us** (*JasperReports Server 7.2*, *Firefox 91.11.0esr*), e.g.:

```css
.jr-mSingleselect-search.jr {  height: auto;  }
```

(hint: since the their forum is closed for new answers during some weeks-long migration process, it was another motivation to post the question and workaround here ...)

Answer (score 0):

For us (***JasperReports Server 7.2*, *Firefox 91.11.0esr***) the following **`override-custom.css`** fix helped:

```css
.control.select .ssPlaceholder {  scale: 1.01;  }
```

It is based on the observation that a client-side page zoom change different from `100%` already makes it work.
So with this in place the select-box is zoomed-in by default some tiny bit (`1.01` times equals `101%` zoom for this specific part) which should not really influence the visual layout but
**(advantage:) fixes the ill behaviour and no workaround has to be applied on the report developers or clients side**.